# How to preload images for iPad Chrome Browser?

Tags: css, html, ipad, google-chrome, preload

I need to preload images which are going to set backgrounds to my web application.I've tried with plain css and plain javascript and css with javascript.they all are working fine with desktop browsers and iPad Safari.but not in chrome.the background is flashing at first time of loading,then it's fine.Any way to get rid of flashing in iPad chrome?

```
body {
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.switchBg {
    background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/331") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size  : 100% 100% ;
}
body:after{
    display:none;
    content: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300") url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/331");
}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uh3jbws5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you want the image to load completely before showing it, it might be loaded only partially hence the flicker.

You can wait for image to load by listening to .onload event from Image instance.

```
image = new Image()

image.onload = function(){
  $("body").addClass("switchBg");
}

image.src = "http://placekitten.com/g/200/331";
```

Hope this helps.

jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/uh3jbws5/2/

Comment: Have you tested with iPad Chrome browser. it's still flashing while switching backgrounds.If you have an iPad,please test with that.
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/uh3jbws5/4/">fiddle</a>

Comment: Still this has the same issue.Sorry,it didn't resolved it.you can check in iPad by adding hyperlink to this fiddle.updated with hyperlink :
http://jsfiddle.net/uh3jbws5/7/